# Neural network fitting tool

Tags: matlab, neural-network

i have built my first neural network in matlab 2009, and i've been playing around with a few datasets; it's going well so far !

I have a question regarding fitting of multiple outcomes: I have five inputs for a single output with more than 2000 data points. i can easily do it for single output. However, now i don not understand how to increase the output to six as i have data for each output.

My question is, how can i increase the number of outputs in neural network fitting tool?

Comment: Very useful : https://www.coursera.org/course/ml  (jump to videos in week 5)

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Please explain in more detail with an example what is it what you want to do, since your question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the outputs that you want in the Target Dataset.  Then you train the model and you will get the same number of outputs that you have in the Target Dataset.